# for different user login i want to display different sidebar options

Tags: angular, angular6

I have created a sidebar component. It has 6 navigation buttons. for different user login, I want to show different navigation buttons.

Suppose I have `A, B, C, D, E` nav options

I want to display :

For user: `A, B, C`

For admin: `A, B, D, E`

Comment: look into auth guards

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you have something like `Auth` service where user data are stored as well as his role(s).

Therefore just inject the service into sidebar

```
constructor (public auth: AuthService, ....) {}
```

and check for the role in template:

```
<a routerLink="component-c" *ngIf="auth.isUser"></a>
<a routerLink="component-d" *ngIf="auth.isAdmin"></a>
<a routerLink="component-e" *ngIf="auth.isAdmin"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can think a solution like this (Everything is an example since you posted no code):

Json responce from your authentication:

```
{
  "username":"Mark",
  "role":"admin"
}
```

define a class like this:

```
export class JsonModelFromBackendLogin{
  username: string;
  role: string;
}
```

your component.ts

```
loginResponce: JsonModelFromBackendLogin;
isLoading = true;

ngOnInit(){
  this.service.login(...)
  .subscribe(responce => {
    this.loginResponce = responce;
    this.isLoading = false;
  });
}
```

your component.html:

```
<ul>
  <li>Section A</li>
  <li>Section B</li>
  <li *ngIf="loginResponce.role == 'user'">Section C</li>
  <li *ngIf="loginResponce.role == 'admin'">Section D</li>
  <li *ngIf="loginResponce.role == 'admin'">Section E</li>
</ul>
```